# Describe all subalgebras of algebra Z(+,2)

Tags: abstract-algebra

How to properly describe all subalgebras of algebra Z(+,2)? 
Where Z means integers, with addition operation and number 2.

I know that all those subalgebras must contain a number 2 and must be closed on addition operation.

As for the specific subalgebras - we take some integers (+ always number 2) as a base and then we add each element with each other. The results we add to our element collection. The process is repeated till "infinity". In the end we found a new subalgebra.
This process in repeated for any subset of Z.

Is this a correct description? And can anyone think of any other more detailed?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by the $2$? An algebra should have an addition, a multiplication and the structure of a ring over some other ring.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I believe the OP means "algebra" in the sense of "universal algebra," that is, a set endowed with some functions (possible 0-ary, e.g. constants are allowed).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Ahh, I see.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft that's not true - the algebra doesn't have subtraction! It just has to be closed under +.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Ohh, good point. I guess I am getting too tired here.

Comment: Funny, Noah's comment still reads as "It just has to be closed under $+.-$, so subtraction doesn't want to go away.

Comment: Aaaaaargh! Now that's gonna bother me. I'd delete the comment, but it seems a shame to lose the comedy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "description." Certainly you've given the right description of the subalgebra generated by some subset of $\mathbb{Z}$; this might be satisfactory for your purposes, I don't know.

One simple observation to make is that - writing "$\langle X\rangle$" for the subalgebra generated by $X\subseteq\mathbb{Z}$ - we have $\langle A\rangle\supseteq\langle B\rangle$ iff each element of $B$ can be written as a nonempty sum of elements of $A\cup\{2\}$.

Another simple observation is that the *asymptotic* structure of a subalgebra will have a nice description, even if the subalgebra itself is messy. For instance, consider the subalgebra $\langle F\rangle$ where $F$ is a *finite* set of *positive* integers. If we let $x=gcd(F\cup\{2\})$, then $\langle F\rangle$ will eventually look like $\{kx: k\in\mathbb{N}\}$, that is, for some $n$ large enough we will have $$\langle F\rangle\cap [n, \infty)=\{kx: k\in\mathbb{N}\}\cap [n, \infty).$$

Comment: "as a sum of elements of $A$" - or $2$, right? And the sum should be finite, but non-empty.

Comment: Ay-ay-ay, I'm on a roll today - fixed. (For me, "sum" means "finite sum," so I've left that part unchanged.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks :). Just a thing about your first observation. Shouldn't it be $\langle A\rangle\supseteq\langle B\rangle$?

Comment: Of course you're right, fixed.